# Animate viewController transition with AutoLayout constraints (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to animate viewControllers with the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` delegate methods and I have some questions.

All example codes that I'd seen use frames to animate views, but I'm using autolayout and it give me problems when animating frame changes.

Having this two views:
[image: First View Controller]
[image: Second View Controller]

I want to animate transition from firstVC to secondVC in this way:

[image: Animation]

So, this is the code I used to do this animation:

```
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)! as! CustomView
    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
    //let cell = fromVC.currentCell //Access to the pressed cell (if needed)

    toView.frame = fromVC.currentFrame //currentFrame is the cell frame saved on fromVC

    toView.autoresizingMask = containerView.autoresizingMask
    toView.layoutIfNeeded()

    containerView.addSubview(toView)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

        toView.frame = containerView.frame
        toView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { _ in

        transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
    })
}
```

As you can see, the animation is not working well because of frame modification and use of AutoLayout.

So, how do you think I can do this animation with constraints?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can share, then I can check your layout.

Comment: I cannot edit my question but I discovered something weird. If I put a backgroundColor on labels, I can see how constraints are respected, but text appears from right to left, instead having textAlignment = .center

Answer (score -1):

You need take a reference view of your Destination view to animate your transition. your source view and destination view should be identically arranged with constrains.

Take snapShot for view to get reference view.

Then use Key frame animation to show transition. Use alpa animation as like in sample code below to make transition feel continuous!

```
    var originFrame: CGRect! 
    // Orginal frame of card view(starting frame)
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
            let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
            let snapshot = toVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
            else {
              return
        }

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVC)

        snapshot.frame = originFrame
        snapshot.layer.cornerRadius = CardViewController.cardCornerRadius
        snapshot.layer.masksToBounds = true

        containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
        containerView.addSubview(snapshot)
        toVC.view.isHidden = true
        fromVC.view.alpha = 1
        snapshot.alpha = 0
        let duration = 0.6

        UIView.animateKeyframes(
            withDuration: duration,
            delay: 0,
            options: .calculationModeCubic,
            animations: {
              UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 1/2) {
                  fromVC.view.alpha = 1
              }

              UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 1) {
                  snapshot.frame = finalFrame
                  fromVC.view.alpha = 0
                  snapshot.alpha = 1
              }
        },
          completion: { _ in
              toVC.view.isHidden = false
              snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
              fromVC.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
              transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })

    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely helpful. Can you _explain_ what we are supposed to learn from your code?